Amazon Linux 2023 on VMware SSL error SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
Downloaded al2023-vmware_esx-2023.6.20241121.0-kernel-6.1-x86_64.xfs.gpt.ova from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/outside-ec2-download.html
Created seed.iso like described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/seed-iso.html
Successfully launched the machine and connected using SSH.
Full setup manual: https://aws.plainenglish.io/complete-guide-running-amazon-linux-2023-on-vmware-configuration-and-setup-instructions-37c9577990cc
When I try to use wget or curl I receive:
[root@amazon-linux-2023 ec2-user]# curl -v https://google.com
* Host google.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2404:6800:4001:802::200e
* IPv4: 142.251.223.78
*   Trying 142.251.223.78:443...
* Connected to google.com (142.251.223.78) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443
* Closing connection
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443

What is wrong? How to fix this issue?

It is much easier to use a vagrant box, for example https://portal.cloud.hashicorp.com/vagrant/discover/gbailey/al2023 It is working fine.
